# Access Multi dimensional array through a dynamic variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a dynamic variable into a multidimensional array.

**This is the actual code**:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($social ["#object"] -> field_sector ["und"]); $i++){
    echo $social ["#object"] -> field_sector ["und"] [$i] ["taxonomy_term"] -> name;
}
```

Since I want to re-use this code for multiple types, I created a function

```
function render_multi_array ($parent, $field_name) {

  for($i = 0; $i < count($parent ["#object"] -> $field_name ["und"]); $i++){
        echo $parent ["#object"] -> $field_name ["und"] [$i] ["taxonomy_term"] -> name;
    }
}
```

The issue is happening with `$field_name` as I am unable to provide this dynamically. Any idea how I can make this function work?

**Sample array is follows**:

```
Array
(
    [#title] => Sector
    [#field_name] => field_sector
    [#object] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vid] => 1079
            [uid] => 30
            [vuuid] => 83ab0817-0175-4541-b20e-93611c20c026
            [nid] => 1077
            [type] => random_study
            [field_random_id] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => CS_525
                                    [format] => 
                                    [safe_value] => CS_525
                                )

                        )

                )
[field_sector] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tid] => 411
                                    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [tid] => 411
                                            [vid] => 10
                                            [name] => Sample title goes here.

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [tid] => 248
                                    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [tid] => 248
                                            [vid] => 10
                                            [name] => Energy


                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

Comment: It does work for me. What is your PHP version?

Comment: PHP version 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 7 the code should work as written. [PHP 7.0 changed evaluation order to strictly left to right](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect).

In PHP 5, you'll get an illegal string offset warning because PHP is trying to first evaluate `$field_name["und"]` (e.g. `"field_sector"["und"]`) and use the result of that as the property name in `#object` rather than evaluating `$parent["#object"]->$field_name` to get the array and then accessing that with `["und"]`.

You can prevent that by bracketing the variable like this:

```
function render_multi_array ($parent, $field_name) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parent["#object"]->{$field_name}["und"]); $i++){
        echo $parent ["#object"]->{$field_name}["und"][$i]["taxonomy_term"]->name;
    }
}
```

Adding those brackets won't cause any problems if you upgrade to PHP 7 later.

By the way, it looks like this code would be simpler with a foreach loop instead.

```
function render_multi_array ($parent, $field_name) {
    foreach ($parent['#object']->{$field_name}['und'] as $item) {
        echo $item['taxonomy_term']->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Perfect solution.

Comment: "1+" for `foreach` idea